# JavaScript: Error "Object doesn't support this action"

Tags: javascript, html

[The code](http://jsfiddle.net/w2JqT/) for a counter gives an error

Whereas [a similar snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/W9L39/) does not

I can't figure out any valid reason...

The line under consideration is:

```
<input type=button name="but2" value="stop" onClick="window.clearTimeout(ID);">
```

The complete code is:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            var counter=0;
            ID=window.setTimeout("start();",2000);
            function start()
            {
                counter++;
                document.forms[0].elements[0].value=counter;
                ID=window.setTimeout("start();",2000);
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="frm1">
                <input type="text" name="timer1">
                <input type="button" name="but1" value="start" onClick="counter=0; start();">
                <input type=button name="but2" value="stop" onClick="window.clearTimeout(ID);">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using and what version?

Comment: This must work on IE9 and the source of error has to be removed, not the warning...

Comment: I have IE9 and I have tried both links.  Both links work.  What exactly is the problem? Are you  copying the code to your local PC?

Comment: Clicking on the status bar (in the local html file)...

Comment: Again, I have downloaded both of these programs to my local PC and they are both working properly.  Have you tried a different browser e.g. Firefox? Are you incorporating the code into an existing webpage,? which contains more JavaScript? Perhaps there is an error elsewhere on the webpage?  Post the code for the entire page and I may be able to help.

Comment: What *is* the error?  Try turning on debugging and see which exact piece of code it comes from.

Comment: There is an error (the one mentioned in the title) that can be seen in IE debugger...he's not completely crazy.

Comment: For me, IE 9 breaks when pressing "start", saying that `start()` is not a function. Renaming `function start()` and its references to something like `function startme()` works fine... No idea why it doesn't like `start` though. (Additional observation: `setTimeout(start, 2000)` is a lot better than `setTimeout("start();", 2000)`.)

Comment: Yeah, IE might be getting mad because of the way you're using setTimeout. The way you're doing it is like using eval() on a string to make it run as code. There are a lot of security issues with eval() , so it would be reasonable for IE to limit its use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.start` instead of start for the `onClick` event. It may be that IE doesn't create a window context when you use code instead of a function for the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about that code there is wrong. Please try to avoid that source of tutorials in the future.

Here is a working script: http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/qTJPx/

List of problem with **your script**:

- missing doctype
- `language="JavaScript"` is deprecated
- variables `ID` and `counter` ended up in global scope
- using html to attach events
- incorrect use of `setTimeout`
- `<script>` tag used in `<head>` when DOM is not ready yet

.. and i don't even want to go over that "similar snippet", it looks like something that by all rights should be dead an buried.

When you add your JavaScript code, it should be right before the closing `</body>` tag, because at that stage the DOM is already ready, but page has not begun to render yet.

I would strongly suggest for you to get some newer materials for learning JavaScript.

Comment: wrong or improper, I have to develop apps for earlier versions...
A good fiddle, but it has to be exactly similar to the (correct) one mentioned in the question.

Comment: what's the problem with using html to attach events? With React everybody do it :-)

Comment: @FezVrasta just because it looks like slapping event callbacks to some html in React, it doesn't mean we're actually doing that. A surprisingly big amount of React internal code deals with event handling, so that we users can have the comfort you describe. But under the hood, a lot is being done so that event listeners do not get added and removed all around the DOM.

Comment: @loopmode, Preact and Inferno don't provide any synthetic events logic and still work just fine

Comment: _"variables ID and counter ended up in global scope"_ Not even remotely important for beginner snippets. _"using html to attach events"_ ...which is fine. _"incorrect use of setTimeout"_ This is not true.

Comment: @Clonkex the "incorrect use" refers to passing **string** instead of executable function. If you do it as a string, then it gets run via `eval` (or maybe via `new Function` .. depends on what the browser actually does). And learning variable scoping is basically the first thing a newbie should learn,

Comment: I know, but it's still valid and therefore not incorrect. Not _recommended_, but not incorrect. As far as variable scoping, sure, they can learn it, but it's by no means automatically bad to have global scoped variables for such an extremely simple page like this. It's much better to make it work first, and make it work well second.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think in this line your getting the error

```
ID=window.setTimeout("start();",2000);
```

Right ?

Put this code

```
var  ID=window.setTimeout("start();",2000);
```

you'll not get this JavaScript: Error `Object doesn't support this action` error.